# problems with this event in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I playing with AngularJS, now when I want to follow this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/johnlindquist/U3c2Q/):

Everthings works untill when I want to fire up the last event: clearCompleted(); My browser complains right away saying:

```
$scope.clearCompleted = function(){

        $scope.todos = _.filter($scope.todos, function(todo){
                    return !todo.done;
                });

    };
```

> ReferenceError: _ is not defined
>       at Object.TodoCtrl.$scope.clearCompleted

and I knwo that it just this event...wondering why? I also dont understand this syntax: _.filter (what is this _.?)
I have feeling that is this: ** _.filter(....**

any idea?

Thanks very much for yr time!
Y/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems as if your trying to use Underscore.js without including it in a script tag.